# JSTL String concatenation - How can we achieve this?

Tags: jstl

In my JSP.. I am now accessing a session scoped variable using ${sessionScope.var1}, $sessionScope.var2}, but i want this 1,2 .. so on, in the var1, to be appended from jstl like ${page} which gives me 0,1,2.. so on.. I tried ${sessionScope.var{page}}, also ${sessionScope['var${page}'] and other things.. but still i am not able to get it.. So, can someone please help me out in this isuue..

Comment: Why not store the values in a List or Array, that way you don't have to dynamically generate a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

try this ;)

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="var${page}" />
${sessionScope[myVar]}
```